# Displaying unix color on windows cmd (e.g. ←[31m)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rspec, cmd, conemu

I've recently started doing some ruby on rails development on Windows 7 and have found a number of commands (rspec, guard, etc) output colour codes that just show up in text on the windows command line (or through Console2 which I use). eg:

```
←[31mrspec ./spec/views/users/index.html.erb_spec.rb:21←[0m ←[36m# users/index renders a list of users←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/homes_spec.rb:9←[0m ←[36m# Homes GET /homes ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/views/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb:13←[0m ←[36m# users/new renders new user form←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/views/users/show.html.erb_spec.rb:13←[0m ←[36m# users/show renders attributes in <p>←[0m
```

I'm aware you can turn the color off for most tools by taking the `--color` command out out of the config files (e.g. the .respc file), but it's a pain to have to do this for everything and colour coding would be nice.

Any ideas how I can get these to display properly in Windows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Change Console2 to [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) (I'm the author of this console). It supports Ansi x3.64
2. Or, you may use AnsiCon to enable Ansi

Comment: I couldn't get AnsiCon to work but ConEmu seems like a great little tool and get's the colours working perfectly, nice work. And thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: Note: The "Inject ConEmuHk" setting must be checked if you want ANSI color to work with second-level processes.

Answer (score 2):

I use Console2 ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ ) with ansicon ( https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon ) and it work well :

1. compile or download dll from author : http://ansicon.adoxa.cjb.net/ and put it in a
   repertory include in your path ;
2. In console, launch ansicon : `ansicon -i`