# What does "m" stand for in rpsec testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I execute:

```
rake spec:models
```

and I get:

```
←[32m.←[0m

Finished in 0.08304 seconds
←[32m1 example, 0 failures←[0m
```

I haven't seen an explication for the "32m1" or "0m" anywhere. What are they?

Answer (score 1):

Those are ANSI escape sequences that would normally tell the console the color the output, or the background of the output.

Check out this related question for a gem you can install that will fix that: [Displaying Unix color on Windows Cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743460/displaying-unix-color-on-windows-cmd-e-g-31m)

You can read more about ANSI escape codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

**edit**

Whoops, that link for the gems actually are for separate consoles, not gems. My bad. I used to use a gem `wirble`, which has been replaced by a new gem called `brice`. You can find `brice` [here](https://github.com/blackwinter/brice#readme). Looks like I also used the `win32console` gem, which is what did the actual conversion of the color codes to the respective console colors. My old `.irbrc` file looks like this:

```
begin
  # load wirble
  require 'wirble'
  require 'win32console'
  include Win32::Console::ANSI

  # start wirble
  Wirble.init
  Wirble.colorize
 rescue LoadError => err
   warn "Couldn't load wirble: #{err}"
end
```